# Why is there no "and" to connect two adjectives?

Tags: grammar

Example 1: Along the coast of northern California grow **huge, towering trees**. Their trunks look like the columns of a great Greek temple.
Example 2: They prefer the **colder, drier** climate found farther inland on the slopes of the Sierra Nevada.

Why is there no "and" to connect **"huge" and "towering"** or "colder" and "drier" in the sentences above?
**"And"** is a conjunction word that is used to connect two words, but why I don't see "and" in the sentences?

Comment: You are asking an unusual, surprising, unexpected, somewhat puzzling question.

Comment: BTW, be more concerned with the *order* of adjectives, e.g., why, "three small red crab apples," not "red crab small three apples"?

Comment: @DrMoishePippik Since it looks as if this question might be closed as a duplicate, why not ask your question as a separate topic? I'd be interested in the answer and I'm a native BrE speaker, but it's never occured to me that we nearly always use that particular order and no other. By the way, the name of the fruit is *crab apple*, so those two words cannot be separated or reversed.

Comment: @PeterJennings Because there are many posts on ELL that already cover that issue. In fact, it has [its own tag](https://ell.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/adjective-order).